# Conflict on jQuery + Bootstrap e.stopPropagation()

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following design using Bootstrap and it's `dropdown.js` in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabardelas/f3wuhjns/):

[image]

Upon clicking the <kbd>Search Criteria</kbd> button, an advance dropdown menu (actually, it is a `form` that implements `dropdown.js`) will be visible. The fallback of this design is that every time you click any element inside the `form`, the form will be hidden (the default behavior of a dropdown menu). Thus, the user cannot type/select any of the form's controls. The solution for that problem would be simple:

```
$("form input, form select")
    .click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

But the problem is the code above also affects the default behavior of the button group `Mode` which is an instance of Bootstrap's Checkbox/Radio `button.js`. The code above causes this button group unchangeable (e.g. Will always select the button `Detailed` even if you click the  button `High Level`).

How can I not make the `dropdown.js` and `button.js` conflict with each other?

Comment: Could you please represent the problem in a jsFiffle ? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: have you tried using `focus()` instead of `click()`? A demo would help

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML ?

Comment: try a manual implementation instead like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ne6mbwfw/2/

Comment: @Alteyss I've attached a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabardelas/f3wuhjns/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that helped me. I didn't avoid using `e.stopPropagation()`:

```
$("form.dropdown-menu, form.dropdown-menu .form-control").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
})

$("form.dropdown-menu label.btn").click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest("form.dropdown-menu").find("label.btn").removeClass("active")
    $(this).closest("form.dropdown-menu").find("label.btn input").removeAttr("checked")

    $(this).addClass("active")
    $(this).find("input").attr("checked", "")

    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

How about stopping propagation, only if the search criteria form is visible?

```
$("form input, form select").click(function(e) {
   if ($("#searchCriteriaFormId").is(":visible") ) {  
     e.stopPropagation();
   } 
});
```